# Heap Sorting Algorithm

Tags: sorting, heapsort

I need the algorithm of HeapSort for sorting the elements of the array, such that all the elements of the array i.e [19 18 14 15 5 7 13 3 8] are in non-decreasing order.

Comment: In what programmin language you need it?

Comment: It is okay to ask here, but wikipedia usually has very good articles on algorithms.

Comment: "Non-decreasing" as in "increasing"?

Answer (score 4):

Read about *Heapsort* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). A nice pseudocode has also been provided.

Answer (score 1):

Heapsort is pretty simple. You grab all elements, put them in a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) (in your case, a max-heap) in any order and then grab them back from the heap (with the delete-max operation) and they come all sorted up.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use IF-free (branchless) [heap sort](http://alg0z.blogspot.ru/2013/02/if-or-no-if.html)